# java junit test: load value dynamically from properties file

Tags: java, junit

I have a junit test class like below:

I want to be able to store the 'key' value in a application properties file.

So when i run my test class, the key value is used.

how will i store my key values in a properties file?

```
public class test { 
    static WebDriver driver;


    @BeforeClass
    public static void BrowserOpen() {
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        int key = 12345;
    }    

    @AfterClass
    public static void BrowserClose() {
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you put the following in `example.properties` in your resources or test-resources folder (that folder is configured in your build tool - such as your Maven or Gradle config or the 'module settings' in IntelliJ):

```
key=12345
```

Then you could load it as follows:

```java
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;

public class PropertiesExample {
    private static int key;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void loadKey() throws IOException {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.load(PropertiesExample.class.getResourceAsStream("example.properties"));
        key = Integer.parseInt(properties.getProperty("key"));
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        System.out.println(key); // prints 12345
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi. In this code I think that there is a mistake. If the properties files does not exist, the getResourceAsStream returns null, and then the load method throws NullPointerException. How we handle this exception in the test method in this case?

Comment: @Thomas_Mylonas You could save the result of getResourceAsStream into a variable, and check if it's null before calling properties.load. If it is, you could throw an exception with a more descriptive message, or (depending on your use case) try to proceed without loading the file. But for usage in a test like this, often the only reason the file would be missing is that the same team responsible for the code forgot to commit the file or create it in the build system. It may be overkill to write code to handle that; you can just go create the file if you ever see the NPE.

Comment: "@brokensandals" Thanks for the reply. In fact, I was doing a test with this and the case that the file was not existing was not caught by the IOException. In a test, you make sure that the file exists in general. But, to store lod to a var and then check is the idea. Thanks a lot again.